# delaying updating value in a for loop

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop, delay

I want to update my price on my webpage with some eyecandy.
What I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#table1").fadeIn(1000, function myLoop()
        {
        var price = 60;

        for ( var i = 0; i <= price; i++ ) {
                $("#price").html("€" + i);              
            }
        });     
    });
```

I need a delay in my For loop so you can see the price iterate upwards.
Any help is being appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In event-oriented environments like web programming, you don't put delays in your code; instead, you yield back to the environment and ask it to call you back in a little while.

In browsers, you do that using `setTimeout` (for a one-off) or `setInterval` (for an ongoing, repeated timer). For what you're doing, I'd use `setTimeout` and schedule each new iteration as required.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table1").fadeIn(1000, function myLoop()
    {
        var price = 60;
        var i = 0;

        loop();

        function loop()
        {
            $("#price").html("€" + i);              
            if (i < price) {
                ++i;
                setTimeout(loop, 100); // 100ms = 1/10th second
            }
        }
    });     
});
```

There, we start with `i` being `0` and call `loop`, which updates the price and then, if `i` is less than `price`, asks the browser to call it back again in 100ms (a tenth of a second). When that happens, it shows that updated `i` value, then repeats the process until `i` is no longer less than `price`.

This works because `loop` is a *closure* over `i` and `price`, which means it has an enduring reference to those variables, even after the `fadeIn` callback has returned (which it does after the first time `loop` runs). More about closures *(on my blog)*: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Answer (score 7):

```
function increasePrice(i, max) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#price").html("€" + i);
        i++;
        if (i <= max) {
            increasePrice(i, max);
        }
    }, 20);
}

increasePrice(0, 200);
```

This will iterate every 20 milliseconds.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/78cWu/

Answer (score 2):

I would write it like this, with `setInterval`:

```
function Start() {

    setInterval(SetPrice, 500);
}

function SetPrice() {

    var ThePrice = $('#ThePrice').text();

    ThePrice = (ThePrice.length) ? parseInt(ThePrice, 10) : 0;

    ThePrice = ThePrice + 1;

    $('#ThePrice').hide()
        .text(ThePrice)
        .fadeIn(300);

    if (ThePrice === 60) { 

        clearInterval(SetPrice); 
    }
}

$(Start);
```

Here's the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SUxZ7/1/)**

It could be much terser but I left it like that for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Price</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#table1").fadeIn(1000, function myLoop() {
            var price = 60,
                i = 0,
                priceTag = $('#price'),
                inter = setInterval(function () {
                    if (++i >= price) {
                        clearInterval(inter);
                    }
                    priceTag.html("€" + i);
                }, 200);
        })
    });
</script>
<div id="table1">
    <div id="price">10</div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```